# Infinite loop when using viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am initializing a custom object from viewDidLoad and calling addSubview from that object, so everytime it updates, viewDidLoad gets called again. I just don't know how to fix it, I'm probably implementing addSubview wrong.

```
SLDViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    SLDSlide *slide1 = [[SLDSlide alloc] initWithImage:@"building-demolition4.gif" numFrames:60 frameWidth:417 totalWidth:25020 height:238];
    [slide1 display];
}
```

Then I'm calling this from "display":

```
- (void) display {
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.image.CGImage, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frameWidth, self.height));

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((screenWidth - _frameWidth)/2, (screenHeight - _height)/2, _frameWidth, _height)];
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

[self.view addSubview:imageView];

NSLog(@"*** Displayed ***");
}
```

The object is of type SLDViewController.

Comment: Share the code that is calling addSubview

Comment: So if you've got an infinite loop where's the code that's looping?

Comment: Did you implement your own addSubview?

Comment: Also, you're not implementing `addSubview`, you're just calling it.

Comment: what is the infinite loop you get?

Comment: It loops at addSubview, "*** Displayed ****" never gets shown. It's because when addSubview loads the view, didLoadview is run again which fires addSubview again, etc. I just don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by moving all the code from viewDidLoad from SLDViewController to SLDAppDelegate DidFinishLaunching.